# Color the days with event on FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My events are displayed with random colors, but instead of that, I would like to have a result like this :

[image: fullcalendar]

I want to color all the days with an event on it. I already made some researches with custom views and the eventRender method but I don't know how to color all days which have an event.
The simplified code to change :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        // here, event.parent().css("background-color:pink;"); ??
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To color the background color of a cell (`td`) that contains an event, you need to find that `td` and change it's background color. Luckily each `td` has a `data-date` so try changing your `eventRender` to,

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
    var eventStart = moment(event.start);
    var eventEnd = event._end === null ? eventStart : moment(event.end);
    var diffInDays = eventEnd.diff(eventStart, 'days');
    $("td[data-date='" + eventStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "']").css('background-color','pink');
    for(var i = 1; i < diffInDays; i++) {
        eventStart.add(1,'day');
        $("td[data-date='" + eventStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "']").css('background-color','pink');
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ! :) However it works only for the first day of each event... Don't fullcalendar have something like : "if this day has an event" ?

Comment: @Didi I've updated my answer to cover events that span more than one day. I don't know if fullcalendar has a "if this day has an event", you might have to dig trough the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfectly :) and yeah I made some researches but I'm handling this server side so I can't use `.fullCalendar("clientEvents")`unfortunately... but your solution is working, thank you a lot !

Comment: @StaticBeagle Thank you for the answer. What about adding green background to available date instead? How can someone achieve this?

Comment: @SarojShrestha my best bet is that you will need to have the list of available dates before you initialize the `fullcalendar` and then change the `eventRender` to deal with coloring the background. However, I suggest you post your question in a new thread and have more people look at it.

Comment: For some reason just changing the css background color makes the cell act weirdly when clicking it. Adding class makes it look normal but then you have to add dynamic classes on the fly. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you need to add `.not(".fc-day-top")` and change it to `background` instead of `background-color` (in my case at least) and it will work right. Man I was doing it such a hacky way before - I think this fixes it. `$("td[data-date='" + eventStart.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "']").not(".fc-day-top").css('background', event.backgroundColor);`

Comment: @user1274820 Thanks for bringing that up. I never had a problem (if my memory serves me right) with the version of `fullcalendar` I was using back then. But they might have changed a few things. I think it would be a good idea to post your comment as an answer for other folks that stumble on this question. Feel free to tag me should you post your answer.